# How can I serve a modified version of an RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feed, rss-reader, feedparser

The problem: I use inoreader.com to monitor a set of RSS feeds. Each of the feeds is generated by pubmed.gov and contains academic journal articles. But there is an annoying quirk where pubmed encodes each author of the article as a separate <dc:creator> item, whereas inoreader will only display the first <dc:creator> item. Other feeds concatenate all authors into a single <dc:creator> item, which is apparently what inoreader expects.

I don't have any control over how pubmed generates the feed or how inoreader interprets it. I wonder if there is a tool I could use to read the pubmed feed, modify it by concatenating all the <dc:creator> items, and re-serve it as a new RSS feed that I can direct inoreader to? The tools I've found so far, such as the feedparser python package, mainly have to do with scraping input, not serving a new feed.